# findFragmentByTag always returning null on trying to retrieve after add()

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have two fragments, I need to keep them both but show and hide on button clicks.

I added the first fragment using:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction();
    mDishFragment = new DishFragment();
    transaction.add(R.id.dish_fragment, mDishFragment, "DishFragment");
    transaction.commit();
```

First fragment (DishFragment) has a button on clicking of which the code checks if "OrderSummaryFragment" exists(using findFragmentbyTag), if it does, it should show() it else add() a new one. here is the code:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("OrderSummaryFragment") == null) {
        System.out.println("OrderSummaryFragment not found");
         transaction.add(R.id.dish_fragment, mOrderSummaryFragment,"OrderSummaryFragment");
         System.out.println("Orderfragment added");
         transaction.addToBackStack(null);
         transaction.commit();
    }else{
        System.out.println("OrderSummaryFragment found");
        transaction.hide(mDishFragment);
        transaction.show(mOrderSummaryFragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

For the first time since "OrderSummaryFragment" doesn't exist, the code adds one and it is displayed. There is a back button on the "OrderSummaryFragment" pressing of which show() up the first fragment "DishFragment".
The second time, since we have already added the "Ordersummaryfragment" previously, the findFragmentByTag should return OrderSummaryFragment but it returns null instead.

Note: I am not using replace() cause I want to reuse both of these fragments.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: To go back to the first fragment you should use PopBackStack ?

Comment: What is R.id.dish_fragment? ;;;;;;;Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment should search for your fragments using the getSupportFragmentManager() instead of the getFragmentManager Method() in your if structure.

BTW, What is that R.id.dish_fragment object? A fragment? A container? It should be a container like a LinearLayout.

Comment: Thanks buddy, Can't believe i missed that :) and yes,  R.id.dish_fragment is a container for fragment.

Comment: Please see my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24833912/refresh-fragment-ui-from-fragmentactivity

Comment: Both methods return a FragmentManager, so it should be the same thing.